# Sentinel 1 missing data

Tags: time-series, sentinel-1, missing-data, colombia

I´m trying to use the complete descending dataset (VV and VH) for a location in Colombia and must got the same number of scenes by band but it does not; in fact, there are 3 missing years of data for the VH and not equal amount of data for the available years.

Something similar happens with the Ascending dataset. How can I get the complete dataset for both or at least one passing?

Comment: Hello Pablo, welcome to gis.stackexchange.com. What location in Colombia are you interested in? What years are missing? Please provide more intormation so as we can help you

Comment: Latitude:  7.95, Longitude: -75.23. Thank you very much.

Comment: In this area, close to Caucasia, you have Sentinel1 images from October 2014 until February 2021 without gaps. What image repository are you using?

Comment: But not the same amount for VV and VH.  I mean, for the area I got this: Descending VV availability since 2014 to 2021, Descending VH availability since 2017 (why?, shouldn´t be the same than VV?), Ascending  VV availability since 2014 but much much fewer than Descending in 2017 and 2018, and Ascending VH availability since 2014 but  much much fewer than Descending from 2014 to 2019. Why such as differences? TKS.